# fill an option text/value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am trying to build a selectlist with javascript :

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

var prg =1;
function add_texte() {
 var objTo = document.getElementById('sousTexte'+str);
 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.innerHTML ='<div">'
   +'<select name="choixType'+ prg +'" id="choixType'+ prg +'">'
   +'<option value="" selected="selected">--choose--</option>'
   +'</select>'
    +'<div id="sousTexte'+prg+'"></div>';
  objTo.appendChild(divtest);
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 {
      formulaire.choixType+i+.options.length= 10;
      formulaire.choixType+i+.options[i].value =i;
      formulaire.choixType+i+.options[i].text =i;
    }
    
  prg++;
   
}

</script>
```

```html
<div>
<select name="choixType0" id="choixType0" >
  <option value="" selected="selected">---choose-</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="btn_add_texte" onclick="add_texte();">
  </button>
</div>
         
<div id="sousTexte0">
</div>
```

I can fill the list if the variable i is fixed : for example if i use :

```
formulaire.choixType1.options[i].value =i;
or
formulaire.choixType2.options[i].value =i;
```

how can i add the variable i with choixType?
thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select name="choixType['+ prg +']" id="choixType'+ prg +'">`

```
var type = 'type2';
formulaire.choixType[type].options[i].value =i;
```

Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: yes that's what i want , but type have to be 2, but when i use formulaire.choixType[2].options[i].value =i; it works and when i use formulaire.choixType[type].options[i].value =i; doesnt work

Comment: Did you defined `var type = "your_type"`  before? Otherwise you need to call it like `formulaire.choixType["your_type"].options[i].value =i;`

Comment: yes i did , and this is the error : 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined' , (thank you RAV for your help)

Comment: `var type = 2` instead of `var type = '2'`

Comment: Just do console.log(formulaire) and check what values actually exists inside. Then - you can use them.